# Nhibernate confused by class inheritance and returns mixed results

Tags: c#-4.0, nhibernate, inheritance, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have a class with a few properties and some methods

```
public class Content
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Application { get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {...}
    public override int GetHashCode() {...}
}
```

With this Fluent NHibernate mapping:

```
public class ContentMapping : ClassMap<Content>
{ 
   public ContentMapping()
   {
      Table("vw_all_contents");

      CompositeId()
                .KeyProperty(x => x.Id, "id")
                .KeyProperty(x => x.Application, "application");

      Map(x => x.Property1, "property1");
      Map(x => x.Property2, "property2");
   }
}
```

Up to here everything works fine.

I now want to populate the same object but with a table a federated table that connects to another database.

So I have:

```
public class ContentOnProductionDatabase : Content { }
```

With a mapping:

```
public class ContenOnProductionDatabasetMapping : ClassMap<ContentOnProductionDatabase>
{ 
   public ContentOnProductionDatabaseMapping()
   {
      Table("vw_federated_all_contents");

      CompositeId()
                .KeyProperty(x => x.Id, "id")
                .KeyProperty(x => x.Application, "application");

      Map(x => x.Property1, "property1");
      Map(x => x.Property2, "property2");
   }
}
```

And here is where NHibernate gets really confused and the queries return mixed results from both databases.

The problem goes away if my ContentOnProductionDatabase does not extend Content but instead is a duplicate class like this:

```
public class ContentOnProductionDatabaseMapping
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Application { get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {...}
    public override int GetHashCode() {...}
}
```

So now everything is fine but I don't like the fact that there is so much code duplication and it seems to me there must be some sort of Mapping configuration out there to force NHibernate to ignore the inheritance and differentiate the two, especially since they map to different databases.

The repository framework is an inbuilt one handles the session and the queries.

```
public class ContentRepository : NHibernateRepositoryBase, IContentRepository
{
    public ContentRepository(INHibernateContext context, ISettingsManager settingsManager): base(context){   }

    public Content ReadContent(int id, string application)
    {
        using (ISessionContainer container = Context.GetSessionContainer())
        {
            return
                container.AsQueryable<Content>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id && c.Application == application);
                    // All queries using <Content> return the correct results
        }
    }

    public ContentOnProductionDataBase ReadFederatedContent(int id, string application)
    {
        using (ISessionContainer container = Context.GetSessionContainer())
        {
            return
                container.AsQueryable<ContentOnProductionDataBase>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id && c.Application == application);
                    // All queries using <ContentOnProductionDataBase> return the combined results of <Content> and <ContentOnProductionDataBase>
        }
    }
}
```

Internally the container.AsQueryable works by invoking this:

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> AsQueryable<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
{
  return LinqExtensionMethods.Query<TEntity>(this.Session);
}
```

Any ideas how to get rid of the code duplication?

Comment: I'm suspecting this  DiscriminatorValue(@"Content"); might be the a possible answer

Comment: "the queries return mixed results from both databases" this might be the expected behavior depending on the queries. Could you elaborate on the queries and returned results vs expected results ?

Comment: I posted the code. It's using the LinqExtensionMethods.Query<TEntity> by NHibernate to query entities

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is in the "Table Per Concrete Class (TPC)" section of http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/232034/Inheritance-mapping-strategies-in-Fluent-Nhibernat  (especially the TPCBaseEntityMap with its `UseUnionSubclassForInheritanceMapping(); )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define the class mapping and the properties only once, you have to define a base class and define the mapping with `UseUnionSubclassForInheritanceMapping` which will allow you to use independent tables per entity which is derived from that base class.

You don't have to but you should declare your base class as abstract, because it will not have a database representation. So persisting the base class will fail! Meaning, you don't want anyone to use it as an entity, instead use your derived classes...

To do so, create one base, and 2 derived classes which should be stored in one table per class.

```
public abstract class ContentBase
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Application { get; set; }
    public virtual string Property1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Property2 { get; set; }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        [..]
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        [..]
    }
}

public class Content : ContentBase
{
}

public class ContentOnProductionDatabaset : ContentBase
{
}
```

The mapping of the base class **must** call `UseUnionSubclassForInheritanceMapping`, otherwise nHibernate would combine the classes.

```
public class ContentBaseMapping : ClassMap<ContentBase>
{
    public ContentBaseMapping()
    {
        UseUnionSubclassForInheritanceMapping();

        CompositeId()
                  .KeyProperty(x => x.Id, "id")
                  .KeyProperty(x => x.Application, "application");

        Map(x => x.Property1, "property1");
        Map(x => x.Property2, "property2");
    }
}
```

The subclass mappings just have to define that the base is abstract.
Here you can also define each table name the entity should use.

```
public class ContentMapping : SubclassMap<Content>
{
    public ContentMapping()
    {
        Table("vw_all_contents");

        Abstract();
    }
}

public class ContentOnProductionDatabaseMapping : SubclassMap<ContentOnProductionDatabaset>
{
    public ContentOnProductionDatabaseMapping()
    {
        Table("vw_federated_all_contents");

        Abstract();
    }
}
```

Comment: I get: Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface error if I do exactly what you have written here

Comment: It fails to query both Content and ContentOnProductionDatabase with the same error

Comment: Really? I copied it 1:1 from a local test project (except the equal.. method)

Comment: Yes, I copied this configuration down to the T. I am not sure why the query fails

Comment: @Nick you're getting cannot instantiate abstract class... error. That means that you try to create a new `ContentBase` I guess. This is of cause not possible, you'd have to either create a new `Content` or `ContentOnProductionDatabaset`...
If the nhibernate session factory construction works fine, it's just an issue with your code which uses the entities...

Comment: But my queries are either <Content> or <ContentOnProductionDB>.
Is it maybe something else missing? Maybe we need empty constructors or something...

Comment: This looks wrong to be. Why does ContentMapping have the "Abstract" thing in it? content is not abstract, its parent is....

Comment: I found the error. The parent MUST NOT be abstract! Otherwise this works well